# Code pushed or uploaded to GitHub shows extra whitespace

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Whenever I push or manually upload code to github extra whitespace will appear in the committed code. I'm using prettier and eslint, I've tried pushing with both enabled and disabled, and with prettier only enabled.

Code as shown on GitHub:
[image]

User Settings:
[image]

Workspace Settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you use tabs instead of spaces? Most editors allow you (like you’ve shown) to customize what a tab character shows as (e.g. 8 spaces). My assumption is that your setting is smaller than what GitHub uses for its display. GitHub *doesn’t* modify your code.

Comment: I use tabs, i set the tab size to 2 in VSCode. Only files that were edited by me in VSCode have this problem.

Comment: @CourtneyScott, the tab size you set in VSCode only configures how tabs are shown in that editor. Your files will still contain literal tab characters, and GitHub displays them with an 8-space width. This is the correct behaviour.

Comment: It’s also possible that your editor has a hook when you save the file that does something funky; like removes the tabs, and turns them into spaces, or the other way around. GitHub, however, shows what is there, and doesn’t munge anything. I’m less sure about your editor....

Answer (score 1):

so setting "prettier.useTabs" to false resolves the issue, you would think that the code being pushed and code being displayed would be the same perhaps this is an issue to push to prettier's git repo but i digress, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "you would think that the code being pushed and code being displayed would be the same"—they _are_ the same. Each contains the very same data. A single tab character can be displayed with different widths: in this case it displays with two-space width in your editor (as you've configured) and eight-space width on GitHub (a common default). That way users can see the amount of whitespace they prefer without having to change the contents of the file. That's pretty much the whole point of tabs (at least, in programming).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to click on `Editor: Insert Spaces` and then make sure that box is checked. Once I changed that, it worked fine for me.